# upper bound on a determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$; show that $|\det(x,y)| \leq \|x\|^{r} \|y\|^{t} \|x-y\|^{s} $, where $s,t,r \in [0,1] $ satisfy $r+s+t =2 $.
Here $\det(x,y)$ is the determinant of the matrix with first column $x$ and second column $y$.

Any hint on how to do this?

This is taken from an analysis prelim exam, so probably not much linear algebra is used

Comment: Previous identical questions found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7C%5Cdet(x%2Cy)%7C%20%5Cleq%20%5C%7Cx%5C%7C%5E%7Br%7D%20%5C%7Cy%5C%7C%5E%7Bt%7D%20%5C%7Cx-y%5C%7C%5E%7Bs%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two hints:

1. $|\det\begin{bmatrix}x & y\end{bmatrix}| \leq \|x\|\|y\|$ since the left-hand side is the area of the parallelogram with sides $x$ and $y$. The same is true if you replace $\|x\|\|y\|$ with any other pair of norms in your inequality.
2. For any $r,s,t$ satisfying your bounds, $(r,s,t)$ is a convex combination of $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$, and $(0,1,1)$. (You can show this directly by computing the weights and proving that they must be non-negative and must sum to 1.)